# permutations of choosing one element or other from two column matrix

Tags: r

Let's say we have a hypothetical complete schedule of potential outcomes from an experiment.

```
Y0<-c(10,15,20,20,10,15,15)
Y1<-c(15,15,30,15,20,15,30)
budgets<-matrix(data=c(Y0,Y1),nrow=7,ncol=2)
```

I would like to list all of the ways to choose two elements from Y1 and the remaining 5 from Y0. Ideally, this would look like an array of 21 lists, each with two elements labeled Y0 and two elements labeled Y1.

**edit:** These are matched pairs, so choosing `y0[1]` removes `y1[1]` from consideration.

Thanks in advance! I think there are many ways to approach this (sapply?) but would appreciate help on the details.

Comment: how about `combn(7,2,function(v) budgets[cbind(1:7,1L+(1:7 %in% v))],simplify = F)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a longer method, there is probably a more compact solution out there:

```
# get within group combinations as matrix
grp0 <-t(combn(Y0, 5))
grp1 <-t(combn(Y1, 2))

# get all possible combos of these rows
grpCombos <- expand.grid(1:nrow(grp1), 1:nrow(grp2))

# get all combinations as a matrix
allGroups <- cbind(grp0[grpCombos[,1],], grp1[grpCombos[,2],])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the combinations of 2 elements from Y1 and and remaining 5 elements from Y0 and only choose one element from each position, try the following code:

```
cb <- as.data.frame(combn(1:7, 2))
sapply(cb, FUN = function(x) c(Y1[x], Y0[-x]))
```

*previous: If you want all the combination of choose 2 from 7 within Y1 and choose 5 from 7 within Y0, the total combination number would be 21 * 21*.

Comment: Hi Jianfeng,

I apologize, I was not clear. You are right that there are 441 possible combos, I think, but these are matched pairs, so choosing `Y0[1]` means that `Y1[1]` is removed from consideration.

Comment: @lmo understood your question in the same way. It is much clearer after your correction.